# Python threaded timer issue

Tags: python, timer

In this piece of code, I expected to see a random element in the list go to 1 for a minimum of 5 seconds.  Frequently I am seeing an element go to 1 for only a couple of iterations, then be reset to 0.  What am I missing?  Does it have to do with threads not shutting down?  Can someone please tell me how to fix it?

```
import threading
import random
import time


def lreset(x):
    global flags
    flags[x] = 0
    return

flags = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

while True:
    index = random.randint(0,7)
    flags[index] = 1
    t = threading.Timer(5, lreset, [index])
    t.start()

    print flags
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because there might be multiple timers waiting to reset the same index. Imagine that on first and third rounds `random.randint` returns same index. In the output for first five rounds the index would be `1`. Then on sixth round the output would be reset back to `0` just as you would expect.

Now if `random.randint` would return the the same index again on seventh round the output would show the index as `1`. Then before the eight round the timer set on third round would reset the index thus it would show as `0` on eight round output.

One way to get the expected behavior is to ensure that you don't set the index if it's already set:

```
while True:
    index = random.randint(0,7)
    if flags[index] == 0:
        flags[index] = 1
        t = threading.Timer(5, lreset, [index])
        t.start()

    print flags
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense.  Thanks.

Comment: Great answer.  Thanks for that.

Comment: @tinker242: No problem, I'm happy if it helps :)